# Using "ps -C java -o pid,user,cmd" Can I reduce the output of cmd?

Tags: text-processing, ps

I am trying to get this command down to just the essential information that I need.

In the command cmd comes back with this output...

```
/usr/local/jre1.7.0_51/bin/java -Dwd.tag=boxect -Dwd.instance=boxect0401a -classpath /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin/boboxecttrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/lib/*:/data/sou/boxect0401a/lib/*:/data/sou/boxect0401a -Dwd.home=/data/sou/boxect0401a -Dwd.service.type=boxect -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/data/sou/boxect0401a/tomcat/conf/log4j.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/data/sou/boxect0401a/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.52 -Dcatalina.base=/data/sou/boxect0401a/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/sou/boxect0401a/temp -Duser.timezone=America/New_York -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=56517 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Doms.base.config=/data/sou/boxect0401a/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties -Xms150g -Xmx150g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:HeapMaximumCompactionInterval=10000 -XX:HeapFirstMaximumCompactionCount=10000 -XX:ThreadStackSize=1280 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=0 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:ErrorFile=/data/sou/boxect0401a/logs/hs_err_%p.log -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/data/sou/boxect0401a/logs/gc.boxect0401a.1415434937.log -Dtrack.instances.accessed=true -Dslave.instanceid= -Dslave.authtoken= -Dslave.tenant= -Dslave.type= -Dslave.target.type= -Drequest.track.id= -Dwd.confidence.level=prod -Dwd.environmentId=PROD org.apache.catalina.startup.Boboxecttrap start
```

I would like to only get the -Dwd.instance and -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port

Is there something I can add to the command to only pull these parts of the cmd?

Edit* Note: I'd still like to see the pid and user responses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the result through `grep -o -- '-Dwd\.Instance=[^ ]*'` (or more likely use `$()` to only run the first half of the pipe once).

Comment: Thanks, I should have been a bit more clear in my posting. I would site like to see the output from pid and user in addition to those two entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the headers off the `ps` output, using the `=` syntax at the end of the column names, then pass the results through `awk` where you ask it to find the positions of those two parameters. Once found, save the matched data into some temporary variables, then print the desired fields at the end:

```
ps -C apache2 -o pid=,user=,cmd= | awk '{
  match($0, "-Dwd.instance=[^ ]+");
  a=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  match($0, "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=[^ ]+");
  b=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  print $1, $2, a, b
}'
```

The `match` function looks for those strings you identified, followed by an equals-sign, followed by "one or more non-blank characters" in order to pick up the parameter values as well.

Given your sample input (faked to provide a PID and user field), the output is:

```
4242 www -Dwd.instance=boxect0401a -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=56517
```